# How to Add Private Function to a button in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

how can i put this code in a button i have tried everything i know

```
  Private Function NewAward(Mark As Double) As String
Select Case Mark
    Case 90 To 100
        Return "High Distinction"
    Case 75 To 89
        Return "Distinction"
    Case 60 To 74
        Return "Credit"
    Case 50 To 59
        Return "Pass"
    Case Else
        Return "Participation"
End Select
End Function
```

Comment: call in button click event .. but what do you expecting from that code ?

Comment: Where is "Mark" coming from? Another control or what?  What do you want to do with the results? Display them to a control or something? Please elaborate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the button to use this text, try somethin like:

```
Button1.Text = NewAward(73)
```

Is that what you want?

If you want to change the code that executes when the button is pressed:

```
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Your code
End Sub
```

Comment: Vb Says that "end of statement expected" with this piece of code               result = NewAward(62) Response.Write("Result:=" & result)

Comment: It works for me. Try to elaborate your problem so we can help better. Better questions make better answers.